# rudder / plugin datasources

Tags: configuration-management, rudder

After having successfully compiled, installed and tested the rudder data sources plugin,
I deleted some datasources values in datasources plugin, but they are still present
into node properties, is it normal ? Trying to delete them manually (with the red cross into node properties) give the following error message :

" An error occured while deleting property 'testxxx': an error occured while updating Node xxxx <- you can not update property 'testxxx' which is owned by provider 'datasources' thanks to provider 'default'

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

The fact that properties remain is the intented behaviour, but it seems to be short sighted as it misses a way to clear all properties from a node.

I see several possibilities here:

- we could delete properties when a datasource is deleted (and with a configurable option to delete them or keep them when the datasource is disabled),
- we could add a "clean" button in datasource for all past datasource to remove them at any time (but that seems ankward),
- we could change the ownership of the property, reverting it to a standard one, when a datasource is deleted (but that does not solve the mass deletion case).

Could you open a bug report in https://issues.rudder.io/projects/datasources/issues/new so that we can track and priorize that change?

In the meantime, you can workaround the problem by:
- creating a new datasource, 
- specify the node property key you want to delete in "property key" field, 
- specify an url that always return 404, 
- in the "what to do in 404" part in the lower part of config, choose "delete property" (should be default).

Ankward, but I don't have a better solution until we address the main problem.